# How to merge two DataFrames of unequal size based on row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames of the type

```
DataFrame 1

Index   Name    Property1 Property2
0     ("a","b")  1          2
1     ("c","d")  3          4
2     ("e","f")  5          6
```

And the second one , has common values , but not at the same index ( which I dont care about).

```
DataFrame 2

Index   Name    Property3 Property4
0     ("g","h")  7          8
1     ("i","j")  9          10
2     ("k","l")  11         12
3     ("a","b")  13         14
4     ("c","d")  15         16
5     ("e","f")  17         18
```

Is there a way to get these to be combined such that the resultant DataFrame is the common rows with the Name shared between the tables?

i.e Result of pandas operation should be

```
Result Frame

Index    Name    Property1 Property2 Property3 Property4
0      ("a","b")  1         2           13       14   
1      ("c","d")  3         4           15       16
2      ("e","f")  5         6           17       18
```

Sorry I am not giving you actual pandas code to create the DataFrames above. But I want to conceptually understand how to join two unequal sized DataFrames with different "indexes" based on a column name . I tried merge and concat and join but dont get the result I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) works fine here, assuming your index actually is your index:

```
In [22]:

df1.merge(df2)
Out[22]:
        Name  Property1  Property2  Property3  Property4
0  ("a","b")          1          2         13         14
1  ("c","d")          3          4         15         16
2  ("e","f")          5          6         17         18
```

Here the `merge` looks for common columns and performs an `inner` merge on those columns.

You can be explicit and specify that you want to merge on the 'Name' column:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Name')
```

but in this case it's not necessary because the only common column is 'Name' anyway.